# If you have me, you'll want more of me.

Tags: riddle

> If you have me, you'll want more of me.
>   But you won't remember getting me.
>   Sometimes you'll want to give me.
>   But if I'm taken, you'll never want me again.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, my regular answer of 'money' doesn't work here, so I guess I ought to try something else...

Is it

> life?

If you have me, you'll want more of me.

> Almost everyone wants to continue living (that is to say, not a lot of people are eager to die).

But you won't remember getting me.

> You don't remember your own birth (unless you're some sort of crazy memory freak, but I'd call that a corner case).

Sometimes you'll want to give me.

> Some people want to have children, to whom they "give life".

But if I'm taken, you'll never want me again.

> You can't want something if your life is taken (i.e. you're dead)!

Comment: You beat me on that. That was my answer :) +1

Comment: Good job!  You nailed it.

Comment: Maybe not remembering is because if you get a longer life your memory will fade of the older memories as well??

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is

Is it

> Loan (of some kind like money)

If you have me, you'll want more of me.

> of course we want more part of it as insured

But you won't remember getting me.

> Sometimes duration is so long for settlement that we wont remember it

Sometimes you'll want to give me.

> Those who are capable can trade using it

But if I'm taken, you'll never want me again.

> Once all money settled we wont need it anymore